# Responsive Modal not packing in enough columns for wrapped flex content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a responsive layout consisting of 150px wide columns that fill a centered `Modal`, and then wrap around when there's not enough space, e.g. on a small screen there might be 1 or 2 columns, on a big screen there maybe 7. The parent is then sized to however many columns fitted. Depending on the page, there may be a different number of columns.

Here is a demo:

```css
.ModalBlur {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    overflow: none;
}

.Modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

section {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
    <div class="Modal">
        <section > Column 1</section>
        <section > Column 2</section>
        <section > Column 3</section>
        <section > Column 4</section>
        <section > Column 5</section>
        <section > Column 6</section>
        <section > Column 7</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, it doesn't wrap more when there is plenty of space. It's a half attempt at wrapping. In the below image you can see it could easily fit 4 columns, but instead, it stays at 2 columns.
[image]

Question: How does one make it use more of the space available (with the parent width not being fixed, as the number of columns varies)?

Side note: I also tried using a CSS grid, but because the width of the Modal is not explicitly set (it adapts to the screen width), the grid auto-fill property does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using width instead of flex basis. This makes the wrapped columns a set width, but the columns in the last row expand as required. And the parent container is an integer multiple of the set column width (not 100%).

```css
.ModalBlur {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    overflow: none;
}

.Modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: calc(100% - 32px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

section {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width:100%;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
    <div class="Modal">
        <section > Column 1</section>
        <section > Column 2</section>
        <section > Column 3</section>
        <section > Column 4</section>
        <section > Column 5</section>
        <section > Column 6</section>
        <section > Column 7</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.ModalBlur {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    overflow: none;
}

.Modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

section {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
    <div class="Modal">
        <section > Column 1</section>
        <section > Column 2</section>
        <section > Column 3</section>
        <section > Column 4</section>
        <section > Column 5</section>
        <section > Column 6</section>
        <section > Column 7</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to make the width of `Modal` div is full (take whole container width )
simply add `width: 100%` to `Modal` to solve this problem.

also, you can change `justify-content: stretch` and make it `justify-content: center`.

this will make content horizontally centered.

```css
.ModalBlur {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    overflow: none;
}

.Modal {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
    <div class="Modal">
        <section > Column 1</section>
        <section > Column 2</section>
        <section > Column 3</section>
        <section > Column 4</section>
        <section > Column 5</section>
        <section > Column 6</section>
        <section > Column 7</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but as stated "The parent is then sized to how ever many columns fitted." I.e it is not just set to 100%.

Comment: Sorry. I've missed that point, even if you tried to change `width: 100%` and make it `flex-grow: 1` this will make the same result